# Data not entering sqlite database - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running "rails console" and then the following command:

```
 User.create(name:"John", email:"test@email.com", password:"foo", password_confirmation:"foo")
```

and i get this:

```
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test@email.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<User id: nil, name: "John", email: "test@email.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$mY0/9RgjwOU46ZYcSC0TFOCMxrPiqWTEHWe1K27O/3Ya...">
```

when i check the file of the sqlite database using SQLite Database browser I see nothing.

here is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    #these attributes can be modified by the users
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    #ruby's way of calling a method below...
    has_secure_password

    #validation testing
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    #regular expression (there is an official one)
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    #and add it..
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
        uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }
    #validate password 
    validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

end
```

why is data not entered in my database?

I get this error with whatever I enter!

This for example:

```
1.9.3p125 :005 > User.create(name:"Smith", email:"smith@email.com", password:"foo", password_confirmation:"foo")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('smith@email.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Smith", email: "smith@email.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$6nzyRJ0IplI6B4bSoQEtUOIcrbFVl1ix3EAKPGJZjZQf...">
```

I never entered a Smith user with that email, and I still get that "User Exists"!

EDIT:

I got the error. The password limit is 5 I was entering a 3-letter password
so when I type this:

```
User.create(name:"Smith", email:"smith@email.com", password:"foobar", password_confirmation:"foobar")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('smith@email.com') LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 00:16:42 UTC +00:00], ["email", "smith@email.com"], ["name", "Smith"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$v/FqAuUPpbdIJ44jVHxbKOJt/uoBTJVkP4KIhzJHNcF8rWPFfKusi"], ["updated_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 00:16:42 UTC +00:00]]
   (266.9ms)  commit transaction
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Smith", email: "smith@email.com", created_at: "2012-03-12 00:16:42", updated_at: "2012-03-12 00:16:42", password_digest: "$2a$10$v/FqAuUPpbdIJ44jVHxbKOJt/uoBTJVkP4KIhzJHNcF8...">
```

I works, but i still get this weird User Exists error... Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you already have a user with the email `test@email.com` so the `:uniqueness` validation for the email is failing.

Comment: What output do you get if you do: `user = User.new(name:"Smith", email:"smith@email.com", password:"foo", password_confirmation:"foo")` and then: `puts user.errors`?

Comment: @TestTest, try something gibberish: `User.create(name:"fwjwof42848yt24", email:"fwjwof42848yt24@email.com", password:"foo", password_confirmation:"foo")` and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: always check `user.errors` - it'll tell you what's up.

Answer (score 8):

Just got here using a Google Search and found what the issue is. In fact, it is a rubbish error message. Even with a clean database it would appear. The problem is: the password is only 3 characters long, wich will cause an issue with

```
    validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}
```

So, if you try with a longer password (and confirmation) it should work.
(PS: I'm using MySQL server, not SQLite, but i'm pretty sure the error is the same)

Comment: This was the solution for me. I was getting the error because my password was one character too short. Good catch Arthur!

Comment: I think `"@messages={:password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}"` is pretty clear really.

Answer (score 8):

1. `user = User.new`
2. set the fields on `user`
3. `user.save`
4. look at `user.errors`

Comment: Checking `user.errors` is THE answer.  There are so many different things that could go wrong.

Comment: Better yet, write an rspec test.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't really help you understand *what* went wrong, just that something did.  If you wrote a test, you'd want it to throw what was in `user.errors` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, that was implied. - there should be an expectation of the error. (ie. password verification failed, length error.)

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit...oh wait...this isn't Python.  Thanks again for the great answer!

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the problem is not "User Exists", and the real reason is that the password is too short.
You can show the errors by inputing the user.errors on the rails console.

please refer to the following error example.

```
irb(main):013:0> user = User.new(name:"caiqinghua", email:"caiqinghua@126.com", password:"admin",password_confirmation:"admin")

=> #<User id: nil, name: "caiqinghua", email: "caiqinghua@126.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$1d5jtpdkpl9hJPr/8s/dku1Y34.Aft/cAP5h/wrTN2sL...">
irb(main):014:0> user.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('caiqinghua@126.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
irb(main):015:0> User.all
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
irb(main):016:0> User.create(name:"caiqing", email:"caiqing@126.com", password:"admin",password_confirmation:"admin")
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('caiqing@126.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<User id: nil, name: "caiqing", email: "caiqing@126.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$Ossfc7NsL6/MjYVEjT5rJe/y4AiqdNZI2tCkrN1h8rHx...">

**irb(main):017:0> user.errors**
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0xba7d34c0 @base=#<User id: nil, name: "caiqinghua", email: "caiqinghua@126.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$1d5jtpdkpl9hJPr/8s/dku1Y34.Aft/cAP5h/wrTN2sL...">, @messages={:password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}>
irb(main):018:0>
```

**If i changed the password from "admin" to "admin123", and nothing is wrong.**

```
irb(main):018:0> 
irb(main):019:0* user = User.new(name:"caiqinghua", email:"caiqinghua@126.com", password:"admin123",password_confirmation:"admin123")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "caiqinghua", email: "caiqinghua@126.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$dHb.jezaiomN.ZE0pazkOOHDdac/K386h7zsORF93HtQ...">
irb(main):020:0> user.save
   (33.7ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (9.9ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('caiqinghua@126.com') LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (108.8ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 27 Sep 2013 15:25:27 UTC +00:00], ["email", "caiqinghua@126.com"], ["name", "caiqinghua"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$dHb.jezaiomN.ZE0pazkOOHDdac/K386h7zsORF93HtQb7wtj73Ha"], ["updated_at", Fri, 27 Sep 2013 15:25:27 UTC +00:00]]
   (112.7ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):021:0> User.all
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 2, name: "caiqinghua", email: "caiqinghua@126.com", created_at: "2013-09-27 15:25:27", updated_at: "2013-09-27 15:25:27", password_digest: "$2a$10$dHb.jezaiomN.ZE0pazkOOHDdac/K386h7zsORF93HtQ...">]>
irb(main):022:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to create a duplicate row in the database where a unique validation exists. See your error message ("User Exists"):

```
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test@email.com') LIMIT 1
```

See the line in your model:

```
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }
```

It's validating that the user's email address is unique. So you must already have a row in the database with "test@email.com" as the email address.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking to the wrong database. This is rails app. and look to the balbla.development schema in database since there is no way about your problem that there must be a row that has same email value

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think

User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('USer@example.com') LIMIT 1

merely checks for uniqueness in that it will run regardless of whether your query will pass or fail.

If you pay a closer attention to the results, you will realize that a successful outcome will display 'User Exists' in blue, while a failed outcome when you actually try to insert a duplicate user will display 'User Exists' in red (or purple in my case).

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too, because of my password is not longer than the 6. So I changed it to the longer one, it worked. But I didn't know why this exception named "User Existed", or
Something wrong with me.
BYW, I didn't open the SQLIte Database Browser.

Answer (score 1):

It's the password.

If you want to check the errors do this:

```
user = User.new(name:"John", email:"test@email.com", password:"foo", 
password_confirmation:"foo")

user.save

user.errors
```